# Function with no name php "Anonymous functions"

Tags: php, function, anonymous-function

**EDIT:**

Found its called "Anonymous functions".

Example:

```
$greet = function($name){
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Title: Function with no name php

I know how functions works in PHP, but I found the code below and I don't understand the call :

> **function ($matches)**

It isn't should be something like:

> **function NAME_OF_FUNCTION ($matches)**

Someone could explain? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an anonymous function : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 2):

The function *itself* is being passed as an argument to `preg_replace_callback`.  Structurally it's basically:

```
preg_replace_callback($some_value, function () { ... }, $another_value);
```

*Inside* of `preg_replace_callback` the function has a name, the name of the argument.  So if it's defined as something like:

```
function preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $input)
```

Then somewhere inside that function it would invoke the one that was passed to it:

```
$callback();
```

The in-line declaration of the function is an [anonymous function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).  The documentation shows a simpler demonstration:

```
$greet = function($name) {
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};
$greet('World');
```